# Selenium does not recognize new tab

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I try to work with multiple tabs with selenium webdriver.
I send the keys Control+t to html body and open a new tab. However web driver does not recognize that I have a new tab and I still have only one item in WindowHandles which equals to CurrentWindowHandle.
I tried to switch to ActiveElement or just sleep for 5 seconds but that didn't help either.
Please help :)

Thanks a lot

Comment: But you can actually see that tab opened?

Comment: Is it reproducible in both chrome and firefox?

Comment: Yes - the tab is opened. Chrome - didn't try. Do you think it is a FF related issue?

Comment: Yeah, could be Firefox related, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28079411/controlling-firefox-tabs-in-selenium and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30258624/selenium-window-handles-not-correct-when-new-window-is-opened-wtih-python.